# How to prevent Javafx Tableview from reloading all displayed Rows, when only certain Items change?

Tags: java, performance, javafx, javafx-tableview

I'm trying to improve the performance of an `Application` with multiple `Tableviews` that are constantly being updated. On each update only 1 item inside the `ObservableList` changes. The reloading of the rows of those `Tableviews` and applying css-styles to these rows are slowing down the application in a significant way.

I looked at the way, that `Tableviews` are reloading their rows and realized that all rows are constantly being reconstructed from scratch independent of the type of change to the underlying `ObservableList`. The changing of 1 item inside the viewport / 1 item outside of the viewport / a complete replacement of the List causes the exact number of row constructions.

Is there a way prevent the Javafx `Tableviews` from reloading all displayed `Rows`, when only certain `Items` change?

Other possible tweaks to improve the performance of constantly reloading `Tableviews` would be greatly appreciated.

```
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class FXApplication extends Application {

    private BorderPane border;
    private TableView<Item> tableView;
    private Button addItemToTv = new Button("Add");
    private Button replaceFirst = new Button("Replace first");
    private Button replaceLast = new Button("Replace last");
    private Button fullReplace = new Button("Full replace");

    private int counter = 0;

    protected Map<Integer, TableRow<Item>> rowsByIndex = new HashMap<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        constructTv();
        setButtonActions();
        Scene s = constructScene();

        primaryStage.setScene(s);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private Scene constructScene() {
        border = new BorderPane();
        border.setCenter(tableView);
        border.setTop(new HBox(addItemToTv, replaceFirst, replaceLast, fullReplace));

        ScrollPane scp = new ScrollPane();
        scp.setFitToHeight(true);
        scp.setFitToWidth(true);
        scp.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
        scp.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
        scp.setContent(border);

        return new Scene(scp);
    }

    private void setButtonActions() {
        addItemToTv.setOnAction(e -> {
            tableView.getItems().add(new Item("bla"));
            Platform.runLater(this::resetCounter);
        });
        replaceFirst.setOnAction(e -> {
            tableView.getItems().set(0, new Item("blub"));
            Platform.runLater(this::resetCounter);
        });
        fullReplace.setOnAction(e -> {
            ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>(tableView.getItems());
            tableView.getItems().setAll(items);
            Platform.runLater(this::resetCounter);
        });
        replaceLast.setOnAction(e -> {
            tableView.getItems().set(tableView.getItems().size()-1, new Item("blub"));
            Platform.runLater(this::resetCounter);
        });
    }


    private void resetCounter() {
        Timeline tl = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), (ee) -> {
            System.out.println(counter + " row calls");
            counter = 0;
        }));
        tl.play();

    }

    private Node constructTv() {
        tableView = new TableView<>();
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++){
            TableColumn<Item, String> col = new TableColumn<>("col " + i);
            col.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
                return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().getString());
            });
            tableView.getColumns().add(col);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 30 ; i++) {
            tableView.getItems().add(new Item("bla"));
        }

        tableView.setRowFactory(param -> {
            TableRow<Item> row = new TableRow<>();
            row.itemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    rowsByIndex.put(row.getIndex(), row);
                    System.err.println("row change " + row.getIndex());
                    counter++;
                });
            });
            return row;
        });

        return tableView;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        FXApplication.launch(args);
    }

}
class Item {
    private String string;

    public Item(String s) {
        string = s;
    }

    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }

    public void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not make sense to use `Platform.runLater` with `Timeline`.  `Platform.runLater(this::resetCounter);` is useless.  Also, you are basically creating new Timelines each time you press a button and all of them are running. That's like the opposite of high performance code (maybe not, but are using a bunch of unnecessary resources). Why the row listener in the cell factory? Why platform.runlater in the cell factory. I feel like everything you are doing is counter to the idea of performance. You need to start with some basic JavaFX tutorials.

Comment: This is just a dummy programm to show the number of times that the RowListener gets called when applying changes to the ObservableList

Comment: yeah, we understand that this is an example - but as @Sedrick already noted: it looks like you are doing all to artificially slow down everything ;) Repeating: there is no need whatever to call Platform.runlater at any of the locations you use it here. Did you really profile your application and which  bottleneck did it reveal?

Comment: ok i agree that the Platform.runlater is obsolete / harmful. Yes i did profile the application and the bottleneck was inside javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow.layoutChildren(). This then calls internal Methods setCellIndex() and applyCss(). I figured the best way to limit these internal calls would be to not construct 50 new rows for every 1 item change.

Comment: Note that you do not measure the creation of new rows here. If I'm not terribly mistaken `TableView` reuses `TableCell`s and `TableRow`s; it just updates them. Depending on the `TableCell` implementations this may be more or less expensive. Depending on the exact details of your application removing `TableView`s that are outside of the viewport may increase the performance. If that doesn't work, you may be required to reimplement the skin for `TableView`. Note that inserting 1 element does indeed require an css update, since different css is applied to odd and even rows...

Comment: In theory if i only change the first item of the ObservableList then only the first row has to be reloaded. The css of the others wont change. Likewise if i edit a item that is not currently displayed in the viewport then no rows would habe to be reloaded. ( Yes rows are recycled and there is one for every displayed item in the viewport, not for every item in the list. So there never was a row for the item outside of the viewport whose edit calls for all current rows to be recycled )